# How to edit RecyclerView´s FloatingActionButton (visibility, etc.)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I´m a new programmer. I need some help with editing a FloatingActionButton created in ListActivity

This is my Activity which contains a FloatingActionButton and RecyclerView in a ConstraintLayout:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        FloatingActionButton fab = ( FloatingActionButton ) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AlarmListActivity.this, FloatingButtonActivity.class));
            }
        });

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RView);
        RAdapter radapter = new RAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(radapter);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can control the view in Activity from adapter of fragment using:

1- add this line to your activity

```
   public FloatingActionButton fab;
```

2- change this line

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = ( FloatingActionButton ) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
```

to

```
fab = ( FloatingActionButton ) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
```

3- In your adapter use this:

```
Activity activity;
 public RAdapter(Activity c) {
        this.activity=c;
    }
```

4- To change the visibility of the view use this line:

```
((AlarmListActivity)activity).fab.setVisibility(Visible);
```

>

>
the second way to do it is set fab `static` and call it from adapter

AlarmListActivity.fab.setVisibility();

but it is not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help you or not given that you speciffically asked for hiding the FAB within the recycler adapter, but if you add a ScrollSListener to the recyclerView like this ->

`recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()`

When adding the ScrollListener, it will ask which methods to load:

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
```

and

```
public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
```

The first one (onScrollStateChanged) will help you know when the recycler stopped scroling. This happens when `newState`'s value is 0

The other method (OnScrolled), will let you know how much or direction the recycler is being scrolled with the variable `dy`

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if(newState == 0){
                    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                if(dy > 0){
                    fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else if(dy < 0){
                    fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

I must tell you, you will get a warning from Android studio but it does work.

fab variable is:

private FloatingActionButton fab;